# converting from decimal base to hexadecimal base c++

Tags: c++, stack, radix

I want to convert from base larger than 10 (11 to 16). This code only converting to base 2-9. How do i convert let say 299 in base 10 = 12B in base 16, 14E in base 15, 1A0 in base 13.... Same goes. Where/how my codes should be? Thank you in advance.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack <int> mystack;
    int input;
    int base;

    cout << "Please enter an integer to be converted (base 10): ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "Base (2 to 16): ";
    cin >> base;

    do {
        int x = input % base;
        mystack.push(x);
    } while (input = input / base);

    cout << "\nThe base " << base << " is:\n";
    while (!mystack.empty())
    {
        int x = mystack.top();
        cout << x << " ";
        mystack.pop();
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Unless this is a homework exercise rather use the `std::hex` IO manipulator and `std::ostringstream` to do this.

Comment: how may i know? in details/codes @user0042

Comment: There's [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) with examples.

Comment: why do you remove the code? without it the question will become invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conversion code is correct: `mystack` contains the right digits, in reverse order.

Your printing code is wrong, though: `cout << x << " ";` with `x` being an `int` will print digits, for bases 11 and above you need letters as well.

One approach is to make a `string` of digits, and use `x` as an index into it:

```
std::string digits("0123456789ABCDEF");
...
while (!mystack.empty()) {
    int x = mystack.top();
    cout << digits[x] << " ";
    mystack.pop();
}
```

Comment: perfect. May you explain to me what happen in this code? @dashblinkenlight

Comment: @SyamilFuad Each character of `digits` represent a character that you need to print for the corresponding digit. For example, `digits[5]` is `'5'`, and `digits[10]` is `'A'`. Hence `digits[x]` produces the right output.

Comment: danke! @dashblinkenlight